# getting GET http://localhost:3000/load net::ER_CONNECTION_REFUSED in google chrome console

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, google-chrome

Am running a node server with angular js to fetch a data from MySQL database table, its working absolutely fine in my local system

But I am accessing the same project via simplehttp server in other machine (ubuntu OS in chromium browser) like http://192.168.1.4/Desktop/Clients/my-folder/my-file am getting the following error in browser console

**GET http://localhost:3000/load net::ER_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

I just searched a lot in google but I did not found any answers still now, please help me to solve this issues

Comment: does only `http://localhost:3000/` url is working?

Comment: @KunalKakkad yes its working in my local system perfectly

Comment: i am little bit confused. You are calling  http://192.168.1.4/Desktop/Clients/my-folder/my-file and you are getting the error as `GET http://localhost:3000/load net::ER_CONNECTION_REFUSED` ?

Comment: @KunalKakkad me too, you have any idea in this

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav Sounds like your simplehttp server is instructed to get page from localhost.  Since it is on another machine, its localhost is not your localhost.

Comment: @Sheepy can you suggest me what should I do to get rid of this error please

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav If this is the case, either point your simplehttp server to the correct ip, or move your node server to it so that they are on same host.  If they are already on same host, check for firewall rule.  For further help, ask server fault.